# указание типа поля в embeded bd из класса-сущности

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2

Пишу сайт и использую embeded db в моем случае это h2 и соответственно hibernate, проблема заключается в том,что поле с типом String оно транслирует в VARCHAR(255), а мне в одной конкретной переменной типа String(в коде называется content) необходимо хранить текст(контент главы), так вот какой аннотацией или каким иным образом можно указать,чтобы эта переменная в бд создавалась с типом TEXT?

код класса-сущности:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class BlogEntry {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String title;

private String content;

private String date;

private int numberInBlog;

@ManyToOne
private Blog blog;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public int getNumberInBlog() {
    return numberInBlog;
}

public void setNumberInBlog(int numberInBlog) {
    this.numberInBlog = numberInBlog;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Blog getBlog() {
    return blog;
}

public void setBlog(Blog blog) {
    this.blog = blog;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}
```

}

Comment: Я пользуюсь hbm.xml файлами, поэтому точно не скажу, но гляньте @Type. По моему именно этой аннотацией тип задается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

возможно кому-нибудь поможет,сделал так,все работает:

```
@Column(name="content", columnDefinition="TEXT")
private String content;
```